# System.Net.HttpWebRequest works infinitely

Tags: c#

I have such function :

```
static void doAction(string link){
  Uri myUri = new Uri(link);
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(ur) ;
  request.GetResponse();
 }
```

After calling this function 2-3 times it always returns with WebException (request timeout expired)  regardless of the value of link.

What's wrong?

Comment: What happens if you set `request.KeepAlive = false;` before getting response?

Answer (score 5):

You're not disposing of the response - which means you'll end up blocking the connection pool if several URLs go to the same host, until those responses are garbage collected.

The simplest fix is just to use a `using` statement:

```
using (request.GetResponse())
{
    // No-op
}
```